# C# create operator overload for concrete type of generic class or struct

Tags: c#, generics, operator-overloading

My type `CRange<T>` is defined as

```
public readonly struct CRange<T>
  where T : struct, IComparable
{
  ...

  public T LowerValue { get; }
  public T UpperValue { get; }
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no `where T: Number`.

I mainly use `CRange<int>` and `CRange<double>`, and there are a couple of situations where I want to multiply a `CRange<>` with a factor (= `double`).

I tried

```
public static CRange<double> operator * (CRange<double> i_range, double i_factor)
```

but this is not allowed, because each operator must contain at least one operand of the type.

Is there any other way to create such an operator?

Comment: You can use extension methods, but they can't be used for define operators. You can define a `Multiply` method though.

Comment: `INumber` *does* exist, so long as you're prepared to enable preview features. [See this article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/)

Comment: @canton7: `INumber` is great! Thanks. But it does not help me here. An extension method likely is the only suitable workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write an extension method -- this is what the runtime does for e.g. [`Vector128<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.intrinsics.vector128?view=net-6.0). This does mean you need a method rather than an operator however.

```
public static class CRangeExtensions
{
    public static CRange<double> Multiply(this CRange<double> range, double factor)
    {
        return new CRange(range.LowerBound * factor, range.UpperBound * factor);
    }

    // Same for int...
}
```

---

If you're OK using preview features, you can make use of [Generic math](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/preview-features-in-net-6-generic-math/) which defines the `INumber<T>` interface:

```
public readonly struct CRange<T> where T : INumber<T>
{
    public T LowerValue { get; }
    public T UpperValue { get; }
    
    public CRange(T lower, T upper) => (LowerValue, UpperValue) = (lower, upper);
  
    public static CRange<T> operator * (CRange<T> range, T factor)
    {
        return new CRange<T>(range.LowerValue * factor, range.UpperValue * factor);
    }
}
```

[SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxANwKYCcoDMCeAfAAQCYBGAWAChKCBmAAnVQgBMB7GAGxzoGcF0ArgGMEdAMIAlCDADmqADwAVAHx0A7gAsMqOorog6ASQByAsMAxLllAN6U6DurV10AMqzUYAahA4CdNnRyCADcdAC+9o7OegCqAA7x3r7+dIHBYZEUjnRRDs6S0nIAFHocHhhwLgKJGACUdAC8qsXunug+fqhVCUkdKagNjXTF5e1VNX11IVF5TvQEJABs4lKyCip0rH0QCKzodABUI4XrVgxF3S5YECL7dXN22TnRAOx0MKhqq5dWxeiXAB0bWSXSOdBud3QVQB60BvVBqWOkL26Gmcyy4SAA=).

Comment: Wow! I knew that `INumber` would bring a lot of benefits, but I didn't realise yet how great they are. This is exactly what we need! Thanks! Can't wait to start using VS 2022 and .NET 6, and hopefully .NET 7 with `INumber` will come out soon.